# PHP preg_replace matching two newline characters

Tags: php, regex

This seems a really simple exercise but It's just not working out for me.

I have a text document, and felt an easy way to HTMLify it is to use a quick regex to translate 2 newlines into a `</p><p>` , this is simple enough for what I need.

So; my regex:

```
\n\h*\n+
/** This matches the newline, 
    then any number (zero or more) whitespace 
    and then a second new line. **/
```

This ***works*** in [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/jJuNvW/1) where I usually trial out my regexes. But in my PHP it's not working;

```
$text = trim($_POST['text']);
$text = strip_tags($_POST['text']);

/*** Find new Paragraphs ***/
$text = preg_replace("/\n\h*\n/","</p>\n<p>",$text);
$text = "<p>".$text."</p>";
```

My input:

```
30th Sep 16

Day 176 has seen more golf balls struck with growing frustration as I try
to train the brain, a short swim, and a dawning realisation which has led
to probably the biggest question that I have ever posed.
```

But my output on PHP is:

```
<p>30th Sep 16

Day 176 has seen more golf balls struck with growing frustration as I try
to train the brain, a short swim, and a dawning realisation which has led
to probably the biggest question that I have ever posed.</p>
```

Adding a `$count` var to the `preg_replace` returns zero, the match is not being found.

Expected output:

```
<p>30th Sep 16 </p>
 <p>Day 176 has seen more golf balls struck with growing frustration as I try
to train the brain, a short swim, and a dawning realisation which has led
to probably the biggest question that I have ever posed.</p>
```

What am I missing? I'm sure it's simple but I can't see why it works on a site but not on my extremely simple script :-/

I have also tried substituting `\n` for `PHP_EOL` and various other permutations of the code, to no success.

Comment: You don't have `\r\n`s do you? How about `\R\h*\R+`

Comment: but the code works on the same text on the regex101 link.

Comment: @bobblebubble yes, \R works. cheers, stick it in an answer :)

Comment: (incidentally I was searching earlier for a special character for newline characters but didn't find `\R` ... I knew the cause of this problem was something silly.....  )

Comment: @dan08 that's just global so it doesn't stop after the first match, habit for working with repeating matches. doesn't apply as `preg_replace` does that automatically

Comment: Oh, my mistake. I thought that's what allowed it to match over multiple lines. Should have tested before commenting

Comment: welcome @Martin, glad it works :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could be that you have `\r\n` line breaks. Try [escape sequence](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrebackslash.html#Misc) `\R` for any linebreak sequence.

```
\R\h*\R+
```

[See demo at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/jJuNvW/2) or [PHP Demo at eval.in](https://eval.in/730064)